# UISearchBar prompt does not animate when it's in the navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, animation, uisearchbar

**Update 03/25/14**

It looks like the lack of animation was a bug in iOS 7.0, and has been fixed in iOS 7.1.

**Original Question**

Normally, when you tap inside a search bar in iOS 7, it has a nice little animation where the magnifying glass and "Search" text slides from the middle of the search bar to the left side. However, if I put the search bar in the navigation bar instead of within a table view, it no longer animates. Instead, the magnifying glass and "Search" text jumps instantly to the left side of the search bar.

You can see this really easily using Apple's [UISearchBar sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848). Open up the storyboard. Add a boolean runtime attribute `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` on Search Display Controller, and check the checkbox it creates. Then, move the Search Bar up a level in the tree, so it is outside of the Table View. Run the project, and the search bar should now be in the navigation bar. Note that when you tap in the search bar, it doesn't animate.

Has anyone successfully put a UISearchBar in the navigation bar in iOS 7, and had it animate properly?

To be clear, my problem is that there is no animation of the search bar between the first and second screenshots below, when the user taps on the search bar.

[image: before] [image: after]

Comment: try with this link https://github.com/iDevAndroid/TableSearch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 7, the UISearchDisplayController supports this by default. Set the UISearchDisplayController's `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES` for to get this working easily.

*Apple Inc Doc:*
Starting in iOS 7.0, you can use a search display controller with a
navigation bar (an instance of the UINavigationBar class) by
configuring the search display controller’s
displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar and navigationItem properties.

**your expected answer**

Remove the search bar from the table view. Using displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar means that UISearchDisplayController will take care of placing the search bar in the hierarchy for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar=YES;   
}
```

[image]

This was not animation first time tap but the animation works good in cancel moments:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{ 
[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES]; 

} 


-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{ 
[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: I'm using displaySearchBarInNavigationBar, but it still does not animate.

Comment: I'm doing this entirely within a storyboard, so there is no code. If you want to see the behavior I'm talking about, you can try moving the search bar into the navigation bar in Apple's UISearchBar sample project, like I describe above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm using a search display controller, yes. I'm sorry, I don't completely understand your updated answer. I'm not having a problem with the search bar going to the top of the screen. My problem is that the "Search" text and magnifying glass icon do not animate when you tap on the search bar.

Comment: could be possible provide your screen shot

Comment: Just added some screenshots to the question.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort iDev. As I said in my question, I've already moved the search bar outside the table view. I also tried setting `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` in `viewDidLoad` instead of as a runtime attribute, and it didn't make any difference. When you run this and tap in the search bar, does the "Search" text animate?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44481/discussion-between-chris-vasselli-and-idev)

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you solve the problem?

Comment: take my example of above link @Andy

Comment: @codercat well it didn't help me cause I had Cancel button always displayed. But I took another approach anyways.